# Delete and rename files using unlink() and rename()

Tags: php

I have a folder, which contains thousands of images for my website products, looking like this:

```
D25200-1.jpg
D25200-2.jpg
D25200-3.jpg
D25201-1.jpg
D25201-2.jpg
D25201-3.jpg
D25201-4.jpg
```

Which means, that product `D25200` has 3 photos and `D25201` has 4 photos.

I want to delete some of the images, but keep the count from 1. For example, if I delete `D25201-1.jpg` and `D25201-2`, the rest of the images to get renamed as `D25201-1.jpg` and `D25201-2.jpg`.

This is the code I've created so far, but it only deletes the photos:

```
<?php
$codes = array(
    'D25201' => '1,2'
);

$dirs = array(
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/products/',
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/products/large/',
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/products/medium/',
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/products/small/'
);

foreach($codes as $code => $photos) {
    $photos = explode(',', $photos);

    foreach($photos as $photo) {
        foreach($dirs as $dir) {
            unlink($dir . $code . '-' . $photo . '.jpg');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the same order?

Comment: Yes, if it's possible, but it's not very important.

Comment: does the $code array contain the items you want deleted?

Comment: Yes, the $codes array contains the code and the photos, that I want to delete. In this example, I want to delete D25201-1.jpg and D25201-2.jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havn't had time to test this but something like this should do it (Or atleast give you a hint at a possible direction the figure the rest out yourself):

```
$codes = array(
    'D25201' => '1,2'
);

$dirs = array(
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/products/',
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/products/large/',
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/products/medium/',
    dirname(__FILE__) . '/products/small/'
);

foreach($codes as $code => $photos) {
    $photos = explode(',', $photos);

    foreach($photos as $photo) {
        foreach($dirs as $dir) {
            if(unlink($dir . $code . '-' . $photo . '.jpg');){
              //if unlink is successfull... loop all images in current dir
                $files = scandir($dir);
                $c = 0;
                foreach($files as $file){
                   $c++;
                   //if the name of the image contains the productcode
                   if(strpos($file,$code) !== false){
                        //rename the file
                        rename ($file , $dir . $code . '-' . $c . '.jpg');
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is probably a better way, using less loops, but something like this should work.